# What Hackenbush game represents oof?

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, surreal-numbers

I have been reading about Hackenbush recently and have learned that the surreal numbers can be represented using RGB Hackenbush. I am having a hard time understanding On, Off, and Oof. What Hackenbush games represent these numbers?

Comment: On is a red edge that grows back when you chop it. Either that, or it is a tower of red edges which is taller than any ordinal number (which does not exist).

Comment: What are On, Off, and Oof in the first place?

Comment: @NoahSchweber They are standard names for fundamental game values in loopy combinatorial game theory. Their definitions can be found in standard texts such as "Winning Ways" and "Combinatorial Game Theory" by Siegel.

Comment: @MarkS. I only have volume 1 of *Winning Ways*, which doesn't cover loopy games, and I don't have Siegel's book; meanwhile, google isn't being very helpful ("on" "off" and "oof" - the latter misconstrued as "of" - generate a lot of false hits). Do you know an online source giving the definitions?

Comment: @MikeEarnest It is possible to have an infinite number of red edges at ground level (think of an infinite number of blades of grass) so that chopping one edge causes no meaningful change.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I know a few other places (presentation slides and arXiv papers) defining "on" and "off". But for "oof", I don't know of a free online source off-hand that isn't [Angel_IG's answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4756761/26369) or [the YouTube video it links](https://youtu.be/ZYj4NkeGPdM)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\textbf{on}$, $\textbf{off}$ and $\textbf{oof}$ are loopy game values in combinatorial game theory, meaning they occur in games in which a position can be repeated.

$\textbf{on}$ is the value of a game in which Left (Blue in Hackenbush) can move to $\textbf{on}$ (the same position, so this is just like skipping a turn) and Right (Red in Hackenbush) has no legal moves. We usually write it as $\textbf{on} = \{\textbf{on}|\}$.

$\textbf{off}$ is similar to $\textbf{on}$, just with the players switched. We write $\textbf{off} = \{|\textbf{off}\}$. $\textbf{on}$ is the highest possible game and $\textbf{off}$ is the lowest: if you add $\textbf{on}$ plus pretty much every game you get $\textbf{on}$ back, a win for Left, except if you add $\textbf{on} + \textbf{off}$, because you would get $\textbf{dud} = \{\textbf{dud}|\textbf{dud}\}$ (Dead Universal Draw).

$\textbf{oof}$ is a game in which Left can move to 0 (the game in which the second player wins) and Right can move to $\textbf{off}$: $\textbf{oof} = \{0|\textbf{off}\}$. It's a hot game in the sense that the players are very incentivized to move there, but it's not the hottest game out there (it's $\textbf{hot} = \{\textbf{on}|\textbf{off}\}$). We similarly also have $\textbf{ono} = \{\textbf{on}|0\}$.

$\textbf{on}$ and $\textbf{off}$ are possible to represent in Hackenbush as a position with infinitely many blue or red branches at ground level, independent of each other (unlike in ordinal-valued positions, where they are in top of each other and so you always leave less than before after chopping one). However, $\textbf{oof}$ and $\textbf{ono}$ are impossible to represent in standard Hackenbush, because we would have to have infinitely many branches of one color being able to be chopped by a single branch of the other color, but we can't have them be on top of the single branch of the other color because then we would have $\textbf{over} = \{0|\textbf{over}\}$ or $\textbf{under} = \{\textbf{under}|0\}$.

For more information, check out the second volume of *Winning Ways* or [this wonderful video for SOME1 that summarizes *Winning Ways* with Hackenbush examples](https://youtu.be/ZYj4NkeGPdM).

Comment: This is wonderful. Thank you! Let me see if I understand. For oof, we might imagine a game where red has infinitely many branches at the ground level and blue has one branch if we add one additional rule to hackenbush: The first player to act across all the moves in the game has the ability to remove all but one of the opponent's branches in a single move. If red goes first, this will always result in off. If blue goes first, this results in the standard hackenbush position with each player left with exactly one branch each.

Comment: @PatrickGambill Exactly! If we add that kind of extra rule, values such as $\textbf{oof}$ are now possible.